# Message Driven Bean with a Datasource

Tags: java, ejb, jms, message-driven-bean

My question is how do I configure an EJB 3.0 style message driven bean to use a configured JMS datasource in jboss.

For example, my MDB looks something like:

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "ExampleMDB", activationConfig = {

        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "MyTopic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "channel", propertyValue = "MyChannel"),

})
@ResourceAdapter(value = "wmq.jmsra.rar")
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class MyMDB implements MessageListener {
 .....
}
```

But I would like the bean to attached to a given JMS datasource ( in the case of jboss 4.2.2 this is in deploy/jms/jms-ds.xml). Perhaps this is not even possible but is worth asking.

Comment: Do you mean you want to manipulate a datasource from the onMessage() method?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, `MyMDB` listens to a topic on WebLogic, and you want to use an additional JMS destination provided by JBoss, defined in a deployed configuration file and identified by its JNDI name (by default, `deploy/jms/jms-ds.xml` only contains the configuration for the JMS provider and connection factories -- no data sources).

The easiest way is to let the container inject the JMS destination and a connection factory via its JNDI name (in JBoss the JMS destinations are configured by [deploying xxx-service.xml files](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/getting_started/v4/html/mdb.html#d0e1617)). On startup you can then initialize the connection, and perform cleanup as soon as the MDB is released.

The following examples shows injection (`@Resource`) and resource managemend (`@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy`). The JMS connection and destination is used in `useJmsDestination(String)` to send a text message.

```
public class MyMDB implements MessageListener {

    @Resource(mappedName = "queue/YourQueueName") // can be topic too
    private Queue targetDestination;

    @Resource(mappedName = "QueueConnectionFactory") // or ConnectionFactory
    private QueueConnectionFactory factory;

    private Connection conn;

    public void onMessage(Message m) {
        // parse message and do what you need to do
        ...
        // do something with the message and the JBoss JMS destination
        useJmsDestination(messageString);     
    }

    private void useJmsDestination(String text) {
        Session session = null;
        MessageProducer producer = null;

        try {
            session = conn.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            producer = session.createProducer(targetDestination);
            TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage(text);
            producer.send(msg);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (producer != null) {
                    producer.close();
                }
                if (session != null) {
                    session.close();
                }
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                // handle error, should be non-fatal, as the message is already sent.
            }
        }
    }


    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        initConnection();
        // other initialization logic
        ...
    }

    @PreDestroy
    void cleanUp() {
        closeConnection();
        // other cleanup logic
        ...
    }

    private void initConnection() {
        try {
            conn = factory.createConnection();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize connection", e);
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection() {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // handle error, should be non-fatal, as the connection is being closed
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is "*How do I specify the JNDI location of the JMS datasource to use for an MDB*?"

In which case the answer is:

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "providerAdapterJNDI", propertyValue = "java:/DefaultJMSProvider")
```

Also, take a look at the following page which provides loads of useful details on configuring MDBs in jBoss:
http://www.jboss.org/community/docs/DOC-9352